# Rolling quantile over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have the following dataframe.
How do i perform a rolling 3 window quantile(0.4) which combines values from 2 columns?

```
### Sample Dataframe
np.random.seed(0) # Freeze randomness
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,size=(20, 1)), columns=list('A'))
b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50,90,size=(20, 1)), columns=list('B'))
df = pd.concat([a,b], axis=1)
df
```

|  | A | B | quantile_AB (expected ans) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6 | 75 | NaN |
| 1 | 1 | 63 | NaN |
| 2 | 4 | 58 | 6.0 |
| 3 | 4 | 59 | 4.0 |

40th percentile of (6,1,4,75,63,58) should give me 6.0.

Below formula gives me the rolling quantile for 2 columns separately.

```
df.rolling(3)[['A','B']].quantile(0.4)
```

Comment: What's the relationship between `A`, `B`?

Comment: no relationship. just numbers as an example

Comment: interlace (zip) the 2 columns and take the rolling quantile over a window of 6, and finally take every 2nd value form that? (or I think rolling lets you also set a step of 2 directly)

Comment: do you have an example in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with rolling quantile

```
df.stack(dropna=False).rolling(window=3*len(df.columns)).\
   quantile(0.4)[cols-1::cols].reset_index(-1, drop=True)
```

**Dataframe**

```
    A   B
0   6   75
1   1   63
2   4   58
3   4   59
```

**Output**:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    6.0
3    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use `numpy` and [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

m = df[['A', 'B']].to_numpy()
W = 3
N = m.shape[1]
Q = 0.4
q = np.quantile(np.reshape(sliding_window_view(m, (W, N)), (-1, W*N)), q=Q, axis=1)
df['quantile_AB'] = pd.Series(q, index=df.index[N:])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    A   B  quantile_AB
0   6  75          NaN
1   1  63          NaN
2   4  58          6.0
3   4  59          4.0
4   8  70          8.0
5   4  66          8.0
6   6  55          8.0
7   3  65          6.0
8   5  50          6.0
9   8  68          8.0
10  7  85          8.0
11  9  74          9.0
12  9  79          9.0
13  2  69          9.0
14  7  69          9.0
15  8  64          8.0
16  8  89          8.0
17  9  82          9.0
18  2  51          9.0
19  6  59          9.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the numpy method. Great alternative solution.
Preferred a pandas based solution but gave an upvote.